# What ID should I use on the business discovery API?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve public stats from Instagram accounts using the business discovery API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/business-discovery) but I'm not sure which node to use to retrieve this data. (I'm new on this API)

I have tried running the example on the site (
?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}) on graph explorer using:

- /me
  {
  "error": {
  "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (Page)",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 100,
  "fbtrace_id": "D0siT4a4GR0"
  }
  }
- my business account id (me?fields=instagram_business_account)
  {
  "error": {
  "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (Page)",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 100,
  "fbtrace_id": "Hq0erqHbbxP"
  }
  }
- my business account's Instagram user id (?fields=instagram_accounts)
  {
  "error": {
  "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (InstagramUser)",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 100,
  "fbtrace_id": "BCAkvwtsZXV"
  }
  }

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

In Graph API Explorer: first call `/me/accounts`. The API should return a list of Pages that you have a Role on, and their IDs:

[image: Screenshot of Graph API explorer with "/me/accounts" path]

Locate the Page that you connected to the Instagram Business Account and click its ID. This will populate the ID in the path field, automatically perform a GET request, and return the Page's name and ID fields.

[image: Screenshot of Graph API explorer with data in JSON format]

Next, click in Search for a field and type `instagram_business_account` until it appears in the typeahead dropdown menu. When you see `instagram_business_account`, click it. This will append the field in the path using the fields parameter. Submit this new request, and you should get back the Instagram Business Account connected to this page.

Now that you have the Business Account ID, see this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

Comment: Even after connecting my Instagram business account to a Facebook page, the /me/accounts endpoint returns an empty set.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: This answer saved my soul.
But my God, how flawed this fb/ig model is…